# Does QPainter in QGLWidget use GPU?

Tags: qt, qglwidget

Do QPainter's APIs in QGLWidget use GPU? 
Or only use CPU to paint but put the result of QPainter to OpenGL's texture ?(just like draw in texture)

After some google, I see that there are some people said that Qt would translate QPainter's api to opengl's calls.

But I also see that there are some people said that QPainter in QGLWidget only use CPU.

I am confused. But I can't find the answer in the document for QGLWidget  (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html)

Could somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Did you research Qt sources?

Comment: I've got tangible performance improvements just from switching to a GL widget in the past, so I'd say it is hardware accelerated. But it really boils down to the particular platform implementation you are using.